# Digits of $n$ factorial

Tags: probability, number-theory, factorial

With the notable exception of $0$, for large enough $n$, the digits in base $10$ for $n!$ seem pretty much uniformly distributed (I have also checked for other few bases $> 2$).

Have anyone noticed this before? How would one prove or disprove this?

Comment: What do you mean by uniformly distributed?

Comment: @kingW3 : I think he means that for large enough $n$, the digits composing $n!$ seem to occur at equal rate, except zero of course.

Comment: It is the most probable thing to happen. The digits (apart from the trailing zeros) are in some sense psuedo-random, so you would expect there to be about as many of each one of them. I would consider it far more worthy of research was this _not_ the case. Also note that the _first digit_ is nowhere near uniformly distributed; $1$ is as likely as $5, 6, 7, 8$ and $9$ combined as a consequence of Benford's law.

Comment: @Arthur, you are right is the most likely thing to happen. I bet looking at the Ring $Z_b$ where $b$ is the base, or even $Z_{b^L}$, being $L$ a fixed maximum length under consideration should settle the matter quickly. This also would explain, if this is the case, why the first digit (or any fixed length _initial_ sequence) does not seem to be random.

Comment: @Arthur, proving that Benford's law applies to factorials takes a bit of work. It's in a paper of Diaconis from about 1976.